# Change first line of GET response in Express

Tags: express, http, server, get, response

When a client emit a GET requisition to my server, the server returns as a first line "HTTP/1.1 200 OK". Its possible change this message to a custom? How I can do it?

I try search in stackoverflow and the documentation.

Comment: This seems like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you want to do that?

Comment: What custom message do you want to change it to? (Depending on what message you want to send, the answer will likely be either "No, that's not possible" or "You can do it like this, but its a really bad idea").

Comment: Iam building a NTRIP Caster and the default response to root endpoint is the message "SOURCETABLE 200 OK" to get all metadata from caster. But using that node framework the response is "HTTP/1.1 200 OK".

Comment: Then the problem is that, since NTRIP is not HTTP and Express is a framework for building HTTP servers, not NTRIP servers, your choice of using Express in the first place appears to be a mistake. Take a look at [Socket.io](https://socket.io/get-started/chat#:~:text=up%20our%20application.-,const%20express%20%3D%20require(%27express%27)%3B%0Aconst%20app%20%3D%20express()%3B%0Aconst%20http%20%3D%20require(%27http%27)%3B,-const%20server%20%3D) which wraps itself around the server before letting Express near it.

Comment: Hi, please share some code

Answer (score 0):

I solve that problem using polymorphism in HttpServer lib of Node. I create my own ServerResponse and overwrite the _storeHeader method.

```
export default class NtripResponse extends ServerResponse {
  statusVersion = 'HTTP/1.1';
  _storeHeader(firstLine: string, headers: OutgoingHttpHeaders) {
    firstLine = this.statusVersion + firstLine.slice(firstLine.indexOf(' '));
    // @ts-ignore Call private _storeHeader
    super._storeHeader(firstLine, headers);
  }
}
```

Therefore, building a server with options modified:

```
    this.server! = http.createServer({
         ServerResponse: NtripResponse,
      ...this.options.tls
    } as ServerOptions);
```

Using that, I can modify the first line of header using the statement:

```
this.res.statusVersion = 'SOURCETABLE';
```

Thanks for all comments.